# Question Be ... like?

Tags: questions, be

I would like to ask if the following sentence is correct:

Q: What will be your typical day at work like?

I am curious about the word order - shouldn't it be "What will your typical day at work be like?"

Answer (score 0):

If you using the word "typical", you are pointing that something is usual or repeated. You must use Present Simple:

What is your typical day at work like?

The word order seems fine to me.